# Problem with pdfcrop on Windows 10

Tags: miktex, pdfcrop

I've been using `pdfcrop` (MiKTeX) from time to time without problems. But I recently moved to a windows 10 machine and now I get an error when pdfcrop is executed:

The error shown is:

```
C:\...\ExperimentsLaTeX>pdfcrop
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at C:/Perl64/lib/Win32/TieRegistry.pm line 718.
```

Response to command `pdfcrop --version` shows: `pdfcrop 2012/11/02 v1.38`

And `perl --version` shows:

```
C:\...\ExperimentsLaTeX>perl --version

This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 1 (v5.20.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2014, Larry Wall

Binary build 2000 [298557] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Oct 15 2014 14:56:57
```

Do you know what's wrong in my system? Is it a known error?

Comment: I think there is for one an (old) bug in pdfcrop, it doesn't look correctly for ghostscript py path on miktex/windows, and now a new bug which is related to the new perl and gives the error when pdfcrop checks the registry. I will write Heiko.

Comment: You can probably avoid the problem with the `--gscmd` option: `>pdfcrop --gscmd mgs.exe`  (or what ever ghostscript you want to use, it should be in the path or add the full path in the option).

Answer (score 1):

What @Ulrike Fischer suggested worked for me: in the windows command prompt i type

```
pdfcrop --gscmd gswin64c.exe myfile.pdf
```

and it crops perfectly. the .exe file comes from the 64 bit installation of ghostscript available at their website.

This also bypasses potentially conflicting versions of ghostscript (might happen when trying to crop in IDEs that have a preinstalled version of ghostscript different from yours), since you are already telling windows which executable to run the cropping with